# iTextSharp, Why when creating a PDF file size is 2 times larger than the original folder with images?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, png, tiff

I need the finished PDF file to be 30% smaller than the original image folder.

There is a folder with images in tiff format. Then I add one image per page (Doc = new document (), etc.), the resulting document size is equal to the size of the image folder. But after passing the doc.Close() PDF file size increased two times (so I use compression PDF later and then the file is approximately equal to the folder), but I need the finished PDF file to be 30% smaller than the original image folder.

Comment: Please share sample code and data to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Most image formats are already compressed, so they won't compress any more. PDFs usually compress because they're mostly text, but one that is mostly images won't.

Also, compression routines usually assume that the data is suitable for compression. If you give them pre-compressed data, the result can be a larger file. It's hard to tell exactly what happened without seeing your files, but I guess that's the reason.

If you want a smaller file, you'll have to reduce the amount of information in your images. Crop them, reduce the colour depth, increase the compression or reduce the number of images.

Comment: I get images from another pdf their format is defined as PNG.
I tried:
1. Leave images in PNG format and add them to PDF (the original image folder is about ~52MB, PDF after all images are added ~52MB, PDF after passing the line in code doc.Close() ~88mb, PDF after compression ~54 )
2. Save images in TIF format without compression (sizes are same as in point 1)
3. Save images in TIF CCITT6 (the source images folder of about ~23Мб, PDF after added all images ~23Мб, PDF after the passage of the lines in the code doc.Close() ~48MB, PDF after compression ~24MB )

Comment: What happens when doc.Close() because of what size inflates? Unpacking? And when the images weren't Packed?

Comment: Without seeing your complete code *and* your files, it is impossible to give a more complete answer than the excellent answer that Robin already gave. (upvoting)

Comment: Like I said, I'd guess the increase in size is due to trying to compress files that are already highly compressed. All the file formats you mention include compression. Try converting one of your files to BMP (it will be much larger) and then ZIP'ing it (it should reduce to something close to the original size)