# Splitted PDF size is larger then orginal file when using the iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, split

I have a pdf file, we need to split it in to separate pages it is working fine but the file size is too large it is causing space issues in my server.

i have verified this thing using c#.net

```cs
using (
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(
        sourceDocument,
        new System.IO.FileStream(_tempFolderPath + component + @"\" + fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create),
    )
)
{
    sourceDocument.Open();
    int pageIndex = startingIndex;
    while (pageIndex <= endingIndex)
    {
        importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(_pdfReader, pageIndex);
        pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
        pageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTextSharp, Why when creating a PDF file size is 2 times larger than the original folder with images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55489699/itextsharp-why-when-creating-a-pdf-file-size-is-2-times-larger-than-the-origina)

Comment: Your code can be improved by using `PdfSmartCopy`. Splitting pdfs in general results in larger summed sizes.